# Change xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation for a wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, xmlserializer, azure-functions

We use WCF client in our project which is an Azure functions app, to communicate with an external web service. We need to change the xmlSerializer's tempFilesLocation because of the permission issue. I searched online and found the following configuration that we can use in our web.config which will solve the problem.

```
<system.xml.serialization>
   <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="an absolute path of your choice"/>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

But in Azure Functions app, we don't have access to web.config, so we need to find a way to do it in the code. Is there any way to change tempFilesLocation in the code?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to modify the web.config for functions running on the dynamic sku (where you pay-per-invocation).

However, if you create your function on the non-dynamic/classic sku (where you pay per vm, the pricing model for regular web apps) then you can modify the web.config settings via an applicationHost.xdt file. More details on how to work with xdt file here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are using dynamic sku approach so we need to find a way to programmatically change the tempFilesLocation in our code. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Comment: @MajidDarabi That would really depend on the library you're using. Your best bet would be to search for how to solve that problem in a separate question that doesn't mention Azure Functions. Just mention that you can't change the web.config file.